# Friendly URL error with Couldn't with id=school_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to implement friendly URLs without using the Gem ,

I have done this;

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :permalink 

  def to_param
    permalink
  end

  def self.find_by_params(input)
    find_by_permalink(input)
  end
end
```

and

```
def show
    @school = School.find_by_params(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @school }
    end
  end
```

but i still get; **Couldn't find School with id=school_name**

I have noticed the problem arises from CanCan

my CanCan file looks like this;

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
       user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
       if user.role == "admin"
         can :manage, :all
       else
         can :read, :all
         can :search, :all
         can [:create, :update, :destroy], Hangout, user_id: user.id
         can [:create, :update, :destroy], SchoolEvent, user_id: user.id
         can [:create, :update, :destroy], SchoolReview, user_id: user.id
         can [:create, :update, :destroy], School, user_id: user.id
         can [:create, :update], Vote, user_id: user.id
         cannot [:create, :update, :destroy], WebEvent

       end    
 end
```

and

```
class SchoolsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show, :search ]
  load_and_authorize_resource
  layout "home_layout", only: [:show]

  def show
    @school = School.find_by_params(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @school }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @Pavan, thank you but it does not solve the problem

Comment: At which line the error is pointing?

Comment: It is an active record error. It simply by passes the new formations.  Parameters: {"id"=>"school_name"}
  School Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `schools`.* FROM `schools` WHERE `schools`.`id` = 0 LIMIT 1

Comment: Try changing this line `@school = School.find_by_params(params[:id])` to `@school = School.find(params[:id])`.

Comment: @Pavan I found the problem to be with cancan. Check the updated code.

Comment: The problem is not "with cancan". The problem is with the default find method cancan is using. As you did't override the default find method cancan gives an error...

Answer (score 0):

I have simply turned `load_and_authorize_resource` to `authorize_resource` to stop loading the resource with the default `find()` function.